# Difference between Application under testing and process.start? Coded UI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

We can launch "calc.exe" using "Application Under Test" and System.Diagnostics.Process.start(), what is the difference.
Can any one share the information? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Process.Start() launches a program and returns it's Process, ApplicationUnderTest launches a program and returns it UITestControl form.

Both can work,  you will simply need to identify the window with Process.Start()

Further, If you have a large amount of Process Arguments, you can do ApplicationUnderTest.FromProcess() with the arguments wrapped, leaving cleaner code.

Comment: plus if your using `Process.Start` with very specific arguments you can then use `ApplicationUnderTest.FromProcess` to wrap that instance. Clean answer, but felt this was useful supplementary.

Comment: @MichaelRieger That's a good addition, I'll edit it in.  Thanks!